# Plot a histogram without the zero values in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

When I try to make a histogram without the zero values, I get an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):.

I have a list of `Beam_irradiance_DNI` values which include several zeroes. I can make histogram, but I don't want the zero values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import csv

# Reading data from csv file
with open('Upington_DNI.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
Hour_of_year = []
Beam_irradiance = []
for row in readCSV:
    hour = row[0]
    DNI = row[1]
    Hour_of_year.append(hour)
    Beam_irradiance.append(DNI)
Hours_since00hrsJan1 = [float(Hour_of_year[c]) for c in       range(1,len(Hour_of_year))]
Beam_irradiance_DNI=[float(Beam_irradiance[c]) for c in range(1,len(Beam_irradiance))]

plt.figure(3)
Beam_irradiance_DNI[ Beam_irradiance_DNI==0 ] = np.nan
plt.hist(Beam_irradiance_DNI, color="grey")
plt.title("Histogram for Beam irradiance - DNI")
plt.xlabel("Beam irradiance - DNI [W/m2]"); plt.ylabel("Probability of  occurrence")
plt.show()
```

I dont know what is wrong here.

Comment: Are these floating point numbers? If so, it's not good enough to check for *exact* equality to zero. You'll want to check whether `abs(val) < epsilon`. Also, rather than replacing with NaN, you could just gran only the non-zero values and create a new array. Then you don't modify your original data. Also it looks like your variable is empty...

Comment: I can't see any zeroes in your list.

Comment: @Suever Thank you for your comments. I have included the entire code. Could you please suggest a method now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only perform logical indexing (`data[data != 0]`) on a [`numpy.array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) *not* a normal python list. If you want to remove values from a python list, you'll want to use a list comprehension to do that.

```
newvalues = [x for x in Beam_irradiance_DNI if x != 0]
```

The other alternative is to actually *convert* your python list to a numpy array.

```
nparray = np.array(Bean_irradiance_DNI)
```

Then you will be able to do the logical indexing you want to perform

```
nparray[nparray == 0] = np.nan
```

The other alternative is to *not* alter the array itself, and simply pass only the non-zero values to `hist`

```
plt.hist(Beam_irradiance_DNI[Beam_irradiance_DNI != 0], color="grey")
```

If you're still having issues with zeros, it's likely due to the fact that these numbers are stored as floating point numbers and their value isn't *exactly* zero. For this you would want to use the following condition to detect "zeros".

```
is_zero = np.absolute(Beam_irradiance_DNI) < np.finfo(float).eps
Beam_irradiance_DNI[is_zero] = np.nan
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! yes, I changed the list into a numpy array and it works now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ArvindSastry if this worked for you please consider marking it as a solution to help people who may search for this same issue.

Comment: @Suever. I am facing an issue "ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer" . Please suggest if i can handle this

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
Beam_irradiance_DNI = np.array(Beam_irradiance_DNI)
plt.hist(Beam_irradiance_DNI[Beam_irradiance_DNI>0], color="grey")
```

this should work because you only keep the elements which are above zero (`Beam_irradiance_DNI>0` is a boolean mask used as index). In case you want to use this further save it as a variable but if you only want to exclude zeros for the histogram don't bother with redefining your variable.

Comment: Hello! I tried this method but it doesn't work. I get an error as follows: TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int(). Yes, I dont want to use this further, I just want to exclude zeros from the histogram

Comment: @ArvindSastry - Perhaps just do ``Beam_irradiance_DNI = np.array(Beam_irradiance_DNI)`` before the ``plt.hist``-line.

Comment: @ArvindSastry - Please don't forget to accept one of the answers for your question. :-)

Comment: @lafemmecosmique you also need to index the condition `array[:,0][array[:,0] > 0]`.

Comment: @MSeifert thank you so much for answering my random question. You've just saved me loads of time on something. Cheers! :)